# Elasticsearch DSL query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "name" : "Danny",
    "id" : "123",
    "lastProfileUpdateTime" : "2021-06-26T20:08:25.089Z"
},
{
    "name" : "Harry",
    "id" : "124",
    "lastProfileUpdateTime" : "2021-04-12T20:08:25.089Z"
},
{
    "name" : "Danny Brown",
    "id" : "123",
    "lastProfileUpdateTime" : "2021-07-26T20:08:25.089Z"
},
{
    "name" : "Danny Smith",
    "id" : "123",
    "lastProfileUpdateTime" : "2021-08-26T20:08:25.089Z"
}
```

I have a usecase where i need to find if a particular id has been updated or not and filter out latest profile. In above case since id:123 has updated profile. so expected outcome should be:

```
{
    "name" : "Danny Smith",
    "id" : "123",
    "lastProfileUpdateTime" : "2021-08-26T20:08:25.089Z"
}
```

If a `id` has more than one entry, pick the one which has latest `lastProfileUpdateTime`.

Comment: how will you find if a particular id has been updated ?

Comment: If a `id`  has more than one entry, pick the one which has latest `lastProfileUpdateTime`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using

1. [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)
   : to group by "id"
2. [Bucket selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html): to get ids where count > 1
3. [Top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html): To get latest document for given id

**Query**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Updated_docs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter_count_more_than_one": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.count>1"
          }
        },
        "latest_document": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "lastProfileUpdateTime": "desc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "Updated_docs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "123",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "latest_document" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 3,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index4",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "huE1i3sBZ5_aIkj8cvpR",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "name" : "Danny Smith",
                    "id" : "123",
                    "lastProfileUpdateTime" : "2021-08-26T20:08:25.089Z"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1630008505089
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```